# LARAVEL - INPUT ERROR - The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to create an input form but couldn't find the solution from the error

[This is what it said](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrDvj.png)

[My View Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkbGy.png)

[My Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lW1CR.png)

[My Router](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZSrx.png)

I've tried some tips online but it still won't work

Comment: Please don't add your code as screenshots, add it as text instead and do so by editing your question. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It's because your route name is not defined. you should add the route name like this

```php
Route::post('CreateItem', 'CreateItem@insert')->name('CreateItem');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think is related to the route name. Have you check which uri is posting the form? Can you try:

```
Route::post('/createItem', function () {
    //
})->name('createItem');
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, got the answer

Route::post('CreateItem','CreateItem@insert');
to
Route::post('/create_item','CreateItem@insert');

and

class CreateItem extends Controller

in my question, I typed the wrong controller name, it should be CreateItem

Thanks for the effort to answer my question tho..